# Extracting date, relation and noun phrase from text

Tags: nlp, text-mining, information-retrieval, nltk, stanford-nlp

A sentence (Segmented from a document) as below:

```
This Amendment dated 26th of April 2018 modifies the Agreement dated 20th April 2017.
or
This Amendment depends on the agreement dated 20th April 2017
```

I would like to extract the following as a CSV

```
Document_type | Date_of_document | relation | related_doc | related_doc_date
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Amendment     | 26-04-2018       | modifies | Agreement   | 20-04-2017
Amendment     | Null             | depends  | agreement   | 20-04-2017
```

**What have I done till now**

Found and extracted dates using Stanford NER. Got them in a normalized form. Can extract Noun Phrases using TextBlob. But cannot link which Noun Phrase is linked to which date.

Am I doing it wrong? Any tutorials/examples/advice?